# Why do top and htop show 0% CPU usage while doing heavy computation inside docker?

Tags: docker, cpu, htop

## Question

top and htop show 0% CPU usage while doing some heavy computation on a video stream inside a docker container. I know for sure that the CPU usage cannot be 0%, as I get correct output of my processed video stream and my own logs (not shown here) show that computations are being performed. Furthermore, running htop (outside Docker) shows that the individual cores of my machine are used, see also the screenshots below.

1. How is this possible?
2. And how can I fix this?

## Screenshots

As this involves work for a company I've removed the names of the processes and non-root users.

Partial screenshot of top from within the Docker container.
[image: top within Docker]

Partial screenshot of top from outside the Docker container.
[image]

Partial screenshot of htop from outside the Docker container. Notice that the individual cores are used.
[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31971/why-does-htop-meter-show-90-while-table-is-0-0

Comment: I think that is unlikely. The top screenshots of the machine are not running in some kind of virtualization. Furthermore, restarting my machine seems to "fix" this issue.. However, sometimes it appears again.